# FCL integration

Tags: ros, fcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use FCL as a collision checker in my own planner that's currently not plugged into Moveit. Is there any documentation or code out there that can help me integrate FCL into my planner? I'm going to be testing on the PR2, so I'd imagine people have done this before Moveit, but I can't find any information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166206/fcl-integration/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The online [doxygen documentation](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/FCL/fcl_docs/webpage/generated/namespacefcl.html) should be helpful. There´s also a wrapper in [OMPL](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1app_1_1FCLMethodWrapper.html#details).

I´d recommend taking a look at the implementation in MoveIt! as a lot of what has been done there will be highly relevant to your use case, too (especially considering that you´re likely also using the PR2 URDF model, so a lot of the link transform setup etc. should transfer). Looking at [this blog post from 2012](https://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/10/09/advancements-flexible-collision-checking-library-fcl) it seems that a lot of FCL is relatively new, so OMPL and MoveIt! are likely the most comprehensive usage examples.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-18**:
Another good source of documentation on usage of FCL is the tests within FCL.